# activeMQ amqp error

Tags: activemq-classic, amqp

I am using activeMQ instead of rabbitMQ,  but still with amqp protocol on the  "app publisher" using log4net.

but got the error below while publishing messages to activeMQ, with some relevant discussion here:  http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/AMQP-version-AMQP-header-mismatch-value-0-expecting-1-td4663920.html

```
INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://localhost:8161/
 INFO | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
 INFO | jolokia-agent: No access restrictor found at classpath:/jolokia-access.xml, access to all MBeans is allowed
org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolException: Could not decode AMQP frame: hex: 414d515001010009
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolConverter.onFrame(AmqpProtocolConverter.java:227)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolConverter.onAMQPData(AmqpProtocolConverter.java:217)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AMQPProtocolDiscriminator.onAMQPData(AMQPProtocolDiscriminator.java:87)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpTransportFilter.onCommand(AmqpTransportFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportException: org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportException: AMQP header mismatch value 1, expecting 0. In state: HEADER4
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportResultFactory$TransportResultImpl.checkIsOk(TransportResultFactory.java:116)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.TransportImpl.input(TransportImpl.java:202)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolConverter.onFrame(AmqpProtocolConverter.java:224)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportException: AMQP header mismatch value 1, expecting 0. In state: HEADER4
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.FrameParser.input(FrameParser.java:186)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.FrameParser.process(FrameParser.java:502)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.TransportImpl.process(TransportImpl.java:1213)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.TransportImpl.processInput(TransportImpl.java:1175)
        ... 9 more
```

Comment: Which AMQP client are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using an incorrect client version.

Note: the RabbitMQ client is  0-9-1 instead ActiveMQ is AMQP 1.0.

check this post:
[Apache Camel AMQP - ActiveMQ AMQP header mismatch value 1, expecting 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099561/apache-camel-amqp-activemq-amqp-header-mismatch-value-1-expecting-0)